# How to return the result of print statement in a function call in python?

Tags: python-3.x, function, printing, ord

I am a beginner and I am having a problem returning a value in python.
The Question is as follows:
Write a function called get_capitals. get_capitals should
accept one parameter, a string. It should return a string
containing only the capital letters from the original
string: no lower-case letters, numbers, punctuation marks,
or spaces.
In short, the function should return the string which will only contain capital letters.
My code is:

```
def get_capitals(a_string):
    for x in a_string:
        ordinal_number=ord(x)
        if ordinal_number>=60 and ordinal_number<=90:
           print(x,end=""))
           # print(ordinal_number)
```

Using function call

```
print(get_capitals("CS1301"))
```

call with the above call the above code i am able to print the result i desire but it returns None.
which I am trying to avoid.
Can someone tell me how can I return a result of the print function?

Comment: You need to use `return variable` to return the result. Also your code should accumulate the capital letters in a variable and then return after the for loop.

Comment: Iam not able to accumulate them on the same line. without using `end=""` and i cannot use `end=""` in return or to assign variables

Comment: `print` doesn't have a "result" in the sense you want; once you have sent something to your program's output, you cannot read it back. The answer is to do something else with your results instead of print them.

Comment: Solved below by vishnudev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehension and join

```
def get_capitals(a_string):
    return ''.join(c for c in a_string if c.isupper())
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding goes, You need a program that only returns letters that is in Capital in a String. I developed a program, have a look.

My Code:

```
    def get_capitals (a_string):
        upper_case_chars = ""
        for i in a_string:
            if i.isupper():
                upper_case_chars = upper_case_chars + i

        return upper_case_chars


    print (get_capitals("CSFF57456"))
```

Comment: No I want to filter out only the capital letters which is a string called in the function call for ex `print(get_capitals("CS1301"))` will only return CS

Comment: I will edit the answer and get back to you soon

Comment: This works fine as well. Appreciate the effort. Also, do check vishnudev's answer. It is subtle.

Comment: sure. but I want to be honest, the answer is too complicated for me. I prefer code that I can understand and explain to someone else if asked. I hope you get it

Comment: yes indeed , vishnus answer was complicated so I dig in a little and it was easy to grasp later.

Comment: That's great. Post questions if you need furthur help